# UITableViewController automatically push UIViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

New to Xcode, new to Obj-C... not new to programming.  I have an iPhone storyboard hierarchy like the one below, and am expecting the UITableViewController to automatically open the UIViewController when I tap on a table item.  It doesn't.

```
  UINavigationController
    - UITableViewController (derived class)
      - UIViewController (derived class)
```

I assumed that because I dragged a link named "Manual Segue, push" from the UITableViewController to the UIViewController in the IB that an automatic connection was made.  No?  What does Manual Segue push mean anyway?  Is there an automatic one?

The UINavigationController offers a "Relationship Segue, root level" link, which seems to be automatic, but the UITableViewController does not.  It only offers Manual Segue.

Some progress was made when dragging a link from the Table Cell to the UIViewController.  That changed the link to "Selection Segue, push" and it sort of works.  Problem is, it crashes when returning to the previous view.  I noticed these log items when tapping a table item:

```
"nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"
"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.  Navigation bar subview tree might be corrupted."
```

Any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I had a leftover call to pushViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the UITableController.  That caused the crash.  My bad.

So the answer was to drag a "Selection Segue, push" link from the table cell to the UIViewController.  Or at least I hope!  I barely know anything at this stage.